# The first frame captured by the canvas becomes completely black after outputting to the img

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, video, base64

I try many articles and methods but still can't solve it, I hope to get a little hint

Then English is not my native language, sorry

```js
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var videobg = document.getElementById('bgc');

  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    }
    var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    img.setAttribute('src', imgURL);
    videobg.appendChild(img);
  })
}
```

```html
  <div class="flexbord">
    <div id="bgc" class="bgc">
      <video id="video" src="https://kwibao-video.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/h7C886i3HFJs98SVUQG5_video_1626853820000.mp4" type="mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>
    <div class="qwe"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a few pieces of code here...

The `img.onload` part works for when you want to draw that `img` on the canvas. Here you are not in this case, you want to draw the `video`, and then (probably) populate the `img` with an image extracted from the canvas.

So **in this case**, you don't need to wait for the image load, you can draw directly the video to the canvas.
However, the `loadeddata` doesn't mean that a frame has been presented to the video element yet, so you may prefer to wait for an other event like `playing` instead.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var videobg = document.getElementById('bgc');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d');
  // draw the video directly
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  var img = new Image;
  // now this represents the canvas, when the video has been drawn on it
  var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  img.setAttribute('src', imgURL);
  videobg.appendChild(img);
}, {
  once: true
});
```

```css
.bgc { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div class="flexbord">
  <div id="bgc" class="bgc">
    <!-- don't forget to set the crossorigin attribute -->
    <video id="video" src="https://kwibao-video.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/h7C886i3HFJs98SVUQG5_video_1626853820000.mp4" crossorigin type="mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="qwe"></div>
</div>
```

However you'd be better avoiding `toDataURL` and prefer `toBlob` instead, which uses a lot less memory

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var videobg = document.getElementById('bgc');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d');
  // draw the video directly
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  var img = new Image;
  canvas.toBlob(async(blob) => {
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    await img.decode(); // wait for the image is loaded
    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    videobg.appendChild(img);
  }, 'image/jpeg');
}, {
  once: true
});
```

```css
.bgc { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div class="flexbord">
  <div id="bgc" class="bgc">
    <!-- don't forget to set the crossorigin attribute -->
    <video id="video" src="https://kwibao-video.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/h7C886i3HFJs98SVUQG5_video_1626853820000.mp4" crossorigin type="mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="qwe"></div>
</div>
```

or, since you are apparently only "presenting" this frame, append the `<canvas>` directly, which is even better memory wise:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var videobg = document.getElementById('bgc');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d');
  // draw the video directly
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  // show the canvas
  videobg.appendChild(canvas);
}, {
  once: true
});
```

```css
.bgc { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div class="flexbord">
  <div id="bgc" class="bgc">
    <!-- don't forget to set the crossorigin attribute -->
    <video id="video" src="https://kwibao-video.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/h7C886i3HFJs98SVUQG5_video_1626853820000.mp4" crossorigin type="mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="qwe"></div>
</div>
```