# Copying from video to canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events, html5-video

I'm trying to load a video and draw a thumbnail from it into a canvas. The problem I have is that I cannot find an event that fires when the video image is ready to copy. When the loadeddata event fires the size is set correctly but the canvas image is blank. If I uncomment the timer to delay for a second then the canvas is filled, but without the delay it isn't. Is there some event I've overlooked, or some other way of telling when the video element is able to copy? I've tried load, canplay, canplaythrough, loadeddata, progress, but none seems to come in at the right time.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var video, image, width, height;
      function copy(src) {
        video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', x => finishCopy()); 
        video.src = src;
      }
      function finishCopy() {
        width = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).width.replace(/[^.0-]/g, '');
        height = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).height.replace(/[^.0-]/g, '');
        image = document.getElementById('image');
        image.width = width;
        image.height = height;
        //setTimeout(draw, 1000);
        draw();
      }

      function draw() {
        let ctxt = image.getContext('2d');
        ctxt.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <video id="video" autostart="false" ></video>
    <canvas id="image"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68512061

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the `loadeddata` event fires as soon as the data for the current frame is loaded, it does not give any hint what that actually means.

In practice however it means that in some cases, or in some browsers it might be able to render the first frame - though you can't depend on it.

The solution is to look for an event, which fires later on in the process of loading/processing the video.

The order those events are happening is as follows:

1. loadstart
2. durationchange
3. loadedmetadata
4. **loadeddata**
5. progress
6. **canplay**

So if we simply take the [`canplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) event instead of `loadeddata`, things should work as expected.

Here's an example:

```js
var video, image, width, height;

function copy(src) {
  video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.addEventListener('canplay', x => finishCopy());
  video.src = src;
}

function finishCopy() {
  width = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).width);
  height = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).height);
  image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.width = width;
  image.height = height;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  let ctxt = image.getContext('2d');
  ctxt.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
}

copy("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4")
```

```html
<video id="video" autostart="false"></video>
<canvas id="image"></canvas>
```

## Edit

After some testing with different browsers it seems that my solution fails in Chrome. Nevertheless I found a workaround which also works in Chrome.

There's a rather undocumented parameter you can append to your video's URL which let's you specify a start position or even a range for your video (`#t=`).

Now if you set the start position to something low like 0.000001 you will still see the first frame of your video AND you're able to draw to the canvas.

However my testing has also shown that this just works in FireFox and Chrome, if you use the `canplaythrough` event instead of `canplay` or `loadeddata`.

Here's the modified example:

```js
var video, image, width, height;

function copy(src) {
  video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', x => finishCopy());
  video.src = src;
}

function finishCopy() {
  width = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).width);
  height = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).height);
  image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.width = width;
  image.height = height;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  let ctxt = image.getContext('2d');
  ctxt.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
}

copy("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4#t=0.000001")
```

```html
<video id="video" autostart="false"></video>
<canvas id="image"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but sorry, that doesn't work for me. I tried the "canplay" event before, and also just now tested your sample code. I inspected the canvas and then added a solid border to be sure I was looking in the right space. The canvas size is correct but it is blank. I also tried it on firefox and safari - it *did* work on Safari but not on Chrome or Firefox. I think either it is browser specific or perhaps a timing issue. My kludgy workaround does work on all 3.

Comment: Sorry russel - I simply forgot to test it in Chrome. I found another workaround though and updated my answer.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much for your effort - not just for a solution but for an understanding of what is happening. This will make supporting other browsers much easier.

Comment: `#t=` is documented in the [media fragments spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#fragment-query)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has a better solution I'd welcome it, but I did find a way to do what I want, by loading the metadata, doing a seek, and then copying the image in the "seeked" event listener. I'm using Chrome, and suspect from what I've read this may not be a general solution, but since for now I'm only supporting Chrome this seems to fulfill my needs.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var video, image, width, height;
      function copy(src) {
        video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', x => video.currentTime = 0);
        video.addEventListener('seeked', x => finishCopy());
        video.src = src;
      }

      function finishCopy() {
        width = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).width.replace(/[^.0-9]/g, '');
        height = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(video).height.replace(/[^.0-9]/g, '');
        image = document.getElementById('image');
        image.width = width;
        image.height = height;
        //setTimeout(draw, 1000);
        draw();
      }

      function draw() {
        let ctxt = image.getContext('2d');
        ctxt.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <button onclick="copy('asd.mp4')">Copy asd.mp4</button>
    <br />
    <video id="video" preload="metadata" autostart="false" ></video>
    <canvas id="image"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```